# How do I find new standard deviation from two means and their SD?

Tags: standard-deviation, meta-analysis

I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate the SD from these below:

Mean glucose 1 = 12.2, SD 1=13.5
Mean glucose 2 = 9, SD 2=8.7

% Change in mean glucose = -35.5%, SD = ?? 
I know calculating % change in mean is quite simple, but how do I calculate SD?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you want to test the difference between two sample means ?

Comment: When you say change, do you mean these are before and after means? If you do then the answer is different from those currently posted.

Comment: it is a before and after mean. For example: mean PREoperation glucose = 12.2, PREoperation glucose SD=13.5; POSToperation glucose =9, POSToperation glucose SD=8.7; sample size for this group is n=10

Comment: I think you should link between your two questions so people can find the correct version.

Comment: By making some strong but plausible assumptions, you can apply the [Delta Method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=delta+method+ratio).  However, your SDs are so large compared to the means that no method will yield reliable estimates of the SD of the ratio.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for decomposition of variances (and its derivation) can be found in [O'Neill (2014)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.2014.966589).  Converted into simple notation for your problem, it is:

$$(n_1+n_2-1) S_{\text{pooled}}^2 = (n_1-1) S_1^2 + (n_2-1) S_2^2 + D_{1,2}^2,$$

where:

$$D_{1,2}^2 = \frac{n_1 n_2}{n_1 + n_2} (\bar{x}_1-\bar{x}_2)^2.$$

In order to apply this formula you also need the sample sizes of the samples.  If you do not have this then it is not possible to derive the pooled variance.

Comment: Sorry, I should've made it more specific. I'm looking at % change from the same population. For example, the values are: mean PREoperation glucose = 12.2, PREoperation glucose SD=13.5; POSToperation glucose =9, POSToperation glucose SD=8.7; sample size for this group is n=10. Hope that clears up a little. Thanks again for your help Ben!

Answer (score 0):

If the two samples are independent the standard deviation of the mean difference is the square root of the sum of squares of SD1 and SD2. The term mean % difference is ambiguous. What is the mean difference, mean1-mean2 or mean2-mean1?

To convert this to a percentage which mean do you put in the denominator, mean1 or mean2? Since you say the mean % difference is -35.5% you are choosing mean2-mean1 and dividing by mean2. Now since mean2 is a sample standard deviation complicates the relationship between the standard deviation of the mean difference and the standard deviation of the % mean differences.

Comment: Sorry, I should've made it more specific. I'm looking at % change from the same population. For example, the values are: mean PREoperation glucose = 12.2, PREoperation glucose SD=13.5; POSToperation glucose =9, POSToperation glucose SD=8.7; sample size for this group is n=10. Hope that clears up a little.